# Is the Japanese verb 'ちらばります’ an intransitive verb or not?

Tags: words, transitivity

Is the Japanese verb 'ちらばります’ an intransitive verb or not?

Comment: Have you looked in any dictionaries?

Comment: Not to sound lazy, but it would be nice to include a definition for the word on requests like these...

Comment: Please use a dictionary first.  Using StackExchange to answer this kind of question is a horribly inefficient way to learn a language.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is: almost a cross between a translation request and a study resources question.

Comment: Here are some tips: 1. Look up the citation form of the verb, which is ちらばる, not the polite form.  2. If you check a Japanese dictionary, look for the 自 (intransitive) or 他 (transitive) labels.  3. If you check jisho.org, it'll say "transitive verb" or "intransitive verb".